# Hibernate 7.0.2: javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm using spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.6.2 in my project, this jar uses hibernate-validator:6.2.0.Final. Recently we decided to move to Hibernate 7.0.2.Final, so I added the following maven config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>${rest.starter.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But now I get the following error during integration testing or run:

> javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

spring-boot-2.x uses javax.validation Annotations and so you need an implementation for javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider.
hibernate-validator:7.0.2 has moved from javax.validation to jakarta.validation and for that it is not downward compatible.

It depends on your project now:
upgrade to spring-boot 3.x ( also upgrade from javax.* to jakarta.* - this might be a huge upgrade )
or downgrade hibernate-validator to version 6.x

I hope I have explained it well :-)

Answer (score 0):

`Springinjecter`'s answer is correct, but now I think it is better to rely only on Spring-Boot which also has a dedicated validator:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I prefer that option instead relying on other third party libraries.